# String array conversion does not work

Tags: arrays, string

I have written this sub to convert the a date in the format 20140101 to 01/01/2014. From the variable inDate I decided to load this into the array arrDate. Each element of the array is correct. It is when I try and put the array back into a string (outDate) I get the following result.

indate=20140101 outDate=97/01/2014
indate=20140202 outDate=98/02/2014

Can anyone say why?

Thanks,

Lawrence

```
private  String convDate (String inDate)    {

    String outDate = "XXXXXXXXXX";


    char[] arrDate  = inDate.toCharArray();
    switch (MainActivity.localloc){
    case "E":
        System.out.println("posO "+arrDate[0]);
        System.out.println("pos1 "+arrDate[1]);
        System.out.println("pos2 "+arrDate[2]);
        System.out.println("pos3 "+arrDate[3]);
        System.out.println("pos4 "+arrDate[4]);
        System.out.println("pos5 "+arrDate[5]);
        System.out.println("pos6 "+arrDate[6]);
        System.out.println("pos7 "+arrDate[7]);

        outDate=arrDate[6]+arrDate[7]+"/"+ arrDate[4]+arrDate[5]+"/"+arrDate[0]+arrDate[1]+arrDate[2]+arrDate[3];

    }

return outDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Button2_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string str = null;
    string s = "20140101";
    str = s.Substring(6, 2) + "/" + s.Substring(4, 2) + "/" + s.Substring(0, 4);
    Interaction.MsgBox(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply. A much better way of solving my problem. I don't know what the difference is between Substring and substring is but the only way I could get it to work with substring was:

```
str=s.substring(6,8)+"/"+s.substring(4,6)+"/"+s.substring(0,4);
```

It seems substring wants the first and last character positions.

Lawrence